# Populate tableview with online file directory

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have the following code

```
 let webPath =  URL(string: "http://peterlinnik.com/Plex%20Music/The%20Beatles%20-%20Discography/Abbey%20Road/")

        do {
            // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
            let webFiles = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: webPath!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
            print(webFiles)


        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

I am trying to populate a tableview with the contents of this directory, at the moment I'm just trying to get it to print what's there but receive the following error,

> The folder “Abbey Road” doesn’t exist.

What am I doing wrong, can this even be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web URL is not a file URL.

Your URL points to an HTML page - this has nothing to do with filesystem folders.

The server's folders that you see displayed via HTML are not exposed directly to you as actual folders.

Comment: Is there any way of scraping this data? It seems to be a pretty standard format.

Comment: Do you have the rights for these music files? :/ Anyway, yes of course its possible, but it's not trivial at all. You'll have to use a library like [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi) to parse the HTML and collect the links.

Comment: That was just an example directory I knew of.. Thanks I'll give that a try